# What is the difference between these two assignments?

Tags: c++, arrays

Here is one way of assigning value to an array

```
char s[2][2];
s[0][0] = 1;
s[0][1] = 2;
s[1][0] = 3;
s[1][1] = 4;
cout << s[0][2];
```

output of this will be some garbage and it keeps changing. But strange thing happens when I do this

```
 char s[2][2];
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i <= 2; i++){
    if(i == 2)
    {
        j++;
        i = 0;
    }
    if(j == 2) break;
    cin >> s[j][i];
}
cout << s[0][2];
```

so as I give input as

`1 2`
`3 4`
the output was `3`?

First of all shouldn't it complain that we are using array beyond its index and secondly why so much difference?

Comment: `s[0][2]` is not an element in your array. Trying to access this element causes [undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior). Once you enter undefined behavior there are no guaranties, your program can do just about anything.

Comment: You have non nul-terminated strings. You access an array after its last element. Sounds like lots of undefined bahaviour.

Comment: C++ and C are different languages.  Your code is not in their intersection.  Tags edited.

Comment: @Gerhardh He is printing a single character, not a `char*`. There is no need for a string terminator.

Comment: "shouldn't it complain that we are using array beyond its index?" No - you can shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: @WeatherVane A warning atleast?

Comment: No. The only protection is memory constraints by the OS. Array lengths are only checked when you initialise them with data at the same time as you declare them. Aside: when you have a function argument which explicilty states the array length such as `void fun(int array[10])` then you still cannot determine the length of the array without being passed that data too.

Comment: Fix the bugs and the mysteries go away. This is why bugs, when found, should be fixed.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux; You are right. My fault.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux C++ requires row-major storage of 2-dimensional arrays, so `s[0][2]` is equivalent to `s[1][0]`.

Comment: UB in your code trying to use s[0][2] which is the third element which doesn't belong to the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the things that makes C and C++ fast is that it **doesn't** check if you go past the bounds of an array.

Instead you get [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  When you trigger this, anything can happen.  Your program may crash, it may appear to work properly, or it may generate strange results.

Comment: so in some cases the second code cannot be certain?

Comment: @DenisKa In both cases you can't depend on the results.  `s[0][2]` is not a valid array index.

Comment: @dbush `s[0][2]` is equivalent to `s[1][0]` because C++ requires row-major storage of multi-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 1):

> First of all shouldn't it complain that we are using array beyond its index

No. The standard does not specify that a program should complain if you use an array out of bounds. The standard specifies that the behaviour is undefined.

> secondly why so much difference?

The behaviour is undefined. In both cases.